# Display an image (document) in a word document (generated from visualforce)

Tags: visualforce, images, document, ms-word

I would like to display an image (which is a document externally available) in a word document (generated from a visualforce page).

The point is that works only if the image URL is with a HTTP and not a HTTPS but unfortunately, all document images are in HTTPS.

I read that I have to use a Salesforce site to display the image but when I use the URL of the site, it is all the time redirected to a HTTPS URL.

Per example, if I use that URL:

> http://mydomain.cs100.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?id=***&oid=***

It is all time that URL which is used:

> https://mydomain.cs100.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?id=***&oid=***

So, the image is not displayed in the word document.

How can I do please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the Document, right click on the image preview at the bottom, and choose "Copy image address" (for Chrome, might be different in other browsers)?

[image]

Mine worked in a VF Word doc in this URL format: https://mydomain.cs83.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=XXX&oid=XXX

Comment: What Microsoft Office  version do you have?

I read that some version don't accept a HTTPS, so that is why I need a HTTP.

http://eplatypus.blogspot.com/2012/01/visualforce-to-word.html
Part "Including Images"

Comment: I'm on O365 and the latest version of Word there. I tried this link in the VF page and it worked just as well: http://mydomain.cs83.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=XXX&oid=XXX